# Inner joining tables (column ambiguously defined)

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a question in an Assignment:

Write a SQL statement that lists **stock item name**, **manufacturer
location city name**, **warehouse location city name** and **stock item
selling price** in ascending STOCKITEM primary key order. The list must
include items with selling price less than or equal to 20 ONLY.

Note 1: You will need to use 4 Inner Join.

Note 2: CITY table has relationships with both WAREHOUSE table and
MANUFACTURER table.

Given Tables:

CITY
MANUFACTURER
WAREHOUSE
STOCKITEM

Relationships:

> 1 CITY may have many MANUFACTURERS
>
> 1 CITY may have many WAREHOUSES
>
> 1 MANUFACTURER may have many STOCKITEMS
>
> 1 WAREHOUSE may have many STOCKITEMS

Following is the code that i wrote:

```
SELECT
  stock.STKNAME      AS "Stock Name",
  stock.SELLINGPRICE AS "Selling Price",    
  ct.CITYNAME        AS "MANUFACTURER CITY",
  ct.CITYNAME        AS "WAREHOUSe CITY"
FROM
  STOCKITEM stock
INNER JOIN WAREHOUSE ware
ON
  stock.WHID = ware.WHID
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER manu
ON
  stock.MANID = manu.MANID
INNER JOIN CITY ct
ON
  ware.CITYID = ct.CITYID
INNER JOIN CITY ct
ON
  manu.CITYID = ct.CITYID
WHERE
  stock.SELLINGPRICE <= 20
ORDER BY
  stock.STKID ASC;
```

My error:

[image]

Comment: You've tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`, yet from your image it appears you're using oracle! I'll remove the tags, please tag the product you use, not those you don't. Also, edit your question to include the actual error, not as an image.

Comment: There are two `INNER JOINS` to `CITY` in your code.

Comment: You have joined to `CITY` twice (on `manu.CITYID` and `ware.CITYID`), but each time you have given it the same alias (`ct`) so this is ambiguous. You need to give each instance of a table it's own alias (e.g. `ct1` and `ct2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias `ct` is being used twice.  You need to fix this throughout the query:

```
SELECT stock.STKNAME      AS "Stock Name",
       stock.SELLINGPRICE AS "Selling Price",    
       ctm.CITYNAME        AS "MANUFACTURER CITY",
---------^
       ctw.CITYNAME        AS "WAREHOUSe CITY"
---------^
FROM STOCKITEM stock INNER JOIN
     WAREHOUSE ware
     ON stock.WHID = ware.WHID INNER JOIN
     MANUFACTURER manu
     ON stock.MANID = manu.MANID INNER JOIN
     CITY ctw
------------^
     ON ware.CITYID = ctw.CITYID INNER JOIN
------------------------^
     CITY ctm
------------^
     ON manu.CITYID = ctm.CITYID
------------------------^
WHERE tock.SELLINGPRICE <= 20
ORDER BY stock.STKID ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
INNER JOIN CITY ct    
        ON ware.CITYID = ct.CITYID    
INNER JOIN CITY ct    
        ON manu.CITYID = ct.CITYID
```

You are joining the same table with the same alias twice, rename one, and it should be fine.